React-Native Installation Error on Windows
I installed node.js, JDK21, AndroidStudio correctly. I set PATH etc. but I have still this problem.[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/6HgVWw7B.png)
https://i.sstatic.net/itp8nQYj.png
As you can see I installed correctly and there is a system variables ss :
[[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/BQsnsszu.png)](https://i.sstatic.net/mdAXstCD.png)
